# Proving that the set of separable elements over a field is a field itself.

Tags: field-theory

My field theory book says that the set of separable elements over a field is a field itself. This roightly translates to the fact that of $a $ and $b $ are separable, so are $a+b,  ab, 1/a$,  etc. I don't quite know how to prove this. Any help would be great.

Comment: This is a hard result in general. Does your book not prove the result later on? What book is it?

Comment: I would disagree with @KCd on the hardness of the result. Seems to me that it can be proved by the correct strategy of going back and forth between separability of an *element* over the field $k$ and separability of an *extension* $K\supset k$. Large number of steps, no one of them particularly hard. (Now I do my homework and see if I can write out all the details.)

Comment: @Lubin,  I would try to prove this without focusing on $a+b$ or $ab$, and prove that if $a$ and $b$ are separable over $k$ then every element of $k(a,b)$ is separable over $k$. Writing out all the details can be tedious, or at least not intuitive, rather than genuinely hard.

Comment: We’re on the same page, @KCd. It’s nowhere as easy or direct as showing that the sum, product, etc. of algebraic elements is algebraic. Ayush, if you’d like me to sketch out my strategy, I can do it in an answer.

Comment: Dear @Lubin, I'd like a sketch.

Comment: If you e-mail me, @Arrow , I’ll send you a copy of something I wrote up a little over four years ago. Three pages.